# Sending an e-mail in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a linux server running, which I back up every day.
The backup script works like a charm, but I would like some feedback on completion with or without errors.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Hier gaan we zoeken naar alle mappen en onderliggende mappen in de LinuxKJ server.
find /var/www -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | while read -d $'\0' foldername
do
        # Hier gaan we alle mappen in zipjes comprimeren en overzetten naar een andere locatie. Overigens laat hij _Inactief eruit.
        fatsoenlijkPad=$(echo $foldername)
        tar --exclude='/var/www/_Inactief' -zcvpf /mediabak/winboxbak/"${fatsoenlijkPad##*/}".tar.gz "$fatsoenlijkPad"
        # Hier gaan we kijken of de functie hierboven een succes return (Succes = 0) (Fout = 1,2,3,4, etc)
        if ( $? == 0 ) then
                Mailtext=$(echo "Backup succesvol.")
        else
                Mailtext=$(echo "Backup failed.")
        fi
done
        # Hier gaan we mailen wat de functie heeft gereturned
        mail -s "Linux backup" "example@example.com"
        $Mailtext
```

./backupscript.sh: line 9: 141: command not found

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Weird way to assign your text variables. Why not simply using Mailtext="Backup Succesvol." and Mailtext="Backup failed" in first place ?

Comment: While talking about text weirdness, I'd go for "successful" as well. ;-)

Comment: Had to edit some dutch text to english for better understanding. Looks like one slipped through my sight ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash `square brackets` are used. Hence change

```
if ( $? == 0 ) then
```

to

```
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
```

Edit: Change

```
mail -s "Linux backup" "example@example.com"
$Mailtext
```

to

```
echo $Mailtext | mail -s "Linux backup" example@example.com
```

To verify that your are able to send and receive a mail, try to send a mail with dummy text as below.

```
echo "Testing Mail" | mail -s "Linux backup" example@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, i edited it to `if [ $? -eq 0 ] then` and that seems to be working!

Comment: The backup is quite big, it is still running. If it is finished and it works, ill make sure to accept.

Comment: Actually, *in bash* you should get into the habit of using `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`. `[` is an alias for `test`, while `[[ ]]` is a builtin feature with extended feature set (e.g. `=~`, locale-aware `<` and `>` etc.), improved performance, and less chance for error (e.g. unquoted variables).

Comment: The problem is though, I have never programmed in bash/linux before, and besides the backup for this server, I don't plan on doing so afterwards. But thanks for a good tip nonetheless

Comment: @SantoshA the backup is finished, but i did not receive an e-mail.

Comment: Check the edit. The problem was with how you construct the mail.

Comment: I will run this code once again. I know i am able to send and receive mails as a simpler version of this code partially worked. It sent me an e-mail but with some weird .bin file in it

Answer (score 0):

As commented, your variable assignement for Mailtext are inefficient (it works, but it has no sense to use an echo command to assign a text value).

As for your email sending, your mail command invocation should be :

```
echo $Mailtext | mail -s "Linux backup" "example@example.com"
```